# Why did I lose the Internet connection after making a home group?

Tags: networking, home-networking, modem, homegroup, wired-networking

I have two computers in my house. They are;

1. laptop with Windows 7 Home Basic
2. desktop with Windows 7 Home Premium

I use internet which is of wired connection and it has a modem. The modem has 1 LAN port and 1 USB port. I connected the desktop to the LAN and Laptop to the USB.

As home group can be made with windows 7 home premium and above versions I made it via desktop. The home group was established and the data can be exchanged.

Now I am able to access internet in desktop but not in laptop. So I tried to share internet but I am not able to do so. Why was the Internet connection on the laptop lost after creating the Home Group?

Comment: Please provide specific router in question.  Why don't you just connect both the desktop and laptop using a traditional lan cable then create the Home Group.  If you do that then it should work how you want.

Answer (score 1):

Hm. That's not a stadard way of doing things. USB can be used to interconnect computers, BUT you need special usb cable AND this is not supported by standard router firmwares.

In other words simple solution for you is to connect small switch to your router and connect pc and laptop to switch. OR you can buy simple Wireless router and connect laptop via wifi.

These devices are cheap and configuration easy.

Switch for exaple: http://amzn.com/B0000BVYT3

[image]

Router for example: http://amzn.com/B002WBX7TQ

[image]

Comment: ^^^ This is the correct answer.